# ASPxGridView GetSelectedFieldValues not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview, selectionchanged

I want to select a row and do something with it's Id column, however it isn't working and I'm running into the error mentioned at the end.
Heres what I got -

### The ASPxGridView snippet -

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small"
  Width="100%" ClientInstanceName="grid" oncustomcallback="grid_CustomCallback"                                              
  onbeforegetcallbackresult="ASPxGridView1_BeforeGetCallbackResult" 
  EnableCallBacks="False" EnableRowsCache="False" KeyFieldName="ID">

... Columns here ...

<ClientSideEvents ContextMenu="OnContextMenu" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" />      
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

#### Note: The grid gets populated via a DataTable

### DataTable code -

```
protected DataTable GetHeadlineData(SqlDataReader rdr)
{
    DataTable headlineTable = new DataTable();        
    headlineTable.Load(rdr)
    headlineTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { headlineTable.Columns["ID"] };
    return headlineTable;
}
```

### PageLoad code -

```
DataTable dt= new DataTable();    
dt= FillGrid(); //this function internally calls the above GetHeadlineData function
Session["headTable"] = dt;
ASPxGridView1.DataSource = Session["headTable"];
ASPxGridView1.KeyFieldName = "ID";
ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
```

### SelectionChanged functions -

```
    function OnSelectionChanged(s, e) {              
        grid.GetSelectedFieldValues("ID", OnGetSelectedFieldValues);            
    }

    function OnGetSelectedFieldValues(result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
            for (var j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
                document.getElementById('selectedRowDiv').innerHTML = result[i];                    
            }
    }
```

### Error I'm getting -

```
A primary key field specified via the KeyFieldName property is not found in the 
underlying data source. Make sure the field name is spelled correctly. Pay 
attention to the character case.
```

Comment: Can you post your `DataTable` by which you load the `gridview`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What eventually worked was using the RowClick event instead of the SelectionChanged.

Answer (score 1):

Try to move your code from the Page_Load to the Page_Init method.  In this case, everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid" ClientInstanceName="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1"
            KeyFieldName="CustomerID" Width="100%">
                    </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

You must provide Unique Ky Column Name **KeyFieldName="Unique Column Name"**